# Issues with Websocket Upgrade header in Nginx while doing proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, websocket

I have 3 `scala` and `akka-http` applications which are binding to `localhost` with different ports in an `ubuntu` machine. I want to access all the applications with the same port number. So I used nginx to proxy the request and redirect to the required port number internally. 
Everything was working fine as expected. Now, in each of the applications, I have in-build websocket built using akka-http. All the websocket request will be having the url .../ws/.. 
Eg:

```
App-1(HR) 
  Url => http://192.168.1.50:90/hr/ ....  nginx resolve to localhost:8181
  web socket url => http://192.168.1.50:90/hr/ws/...

App-2(Common) 
  Url => http://192.168.1.50:90/common/... nginx resolve to localhost:8182
  web socket url => http://192.168.1.50:90/common/ws/... 

App-3(accounts) 
  Url => http://192.168.1.50/accounts/.. nginx resolve to localhost:8183
  web socket url => http://192.168.1.50:90/accounts/ws/...
```

Websocket was working fine in my machine, but when I deployed to ubuntu server, it is giving errors in websocket. After checking the log, I found out the reason that, when the nginx proxy is done, it will not be carrying over the `Upgrade` header. So I made the following change in the nginx configuration file for the `location` element.

```
location /common {
                location /common/global {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8182/common/ws;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                }
                location /common {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8182/common;
                }
}
```

Now the websocket is working fine. However, I need to add this to the two other location elements also. 
**I am not sure if this is the correct approach for doing this. Can anyone please guide me with this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the inspector in Chrome at your headers. It sends a capital `Upgrade` not `upgrade`. I'm not sure if that's your only problem, but mine wouldn't work until this was fixed.

`proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";`

should be

`proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";`